# iOS custom keyboard loading issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint, custom-keyboard

I am creating a custom keyboard on iOS using Objective-C. To increase the height of the keyboard to make it same as default keyboard height (with suggestions bar) for both portrait and landscape, I have added height constraints programatically { I removed the previously added constraint before adding the new one }.

I am updating the height in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the class so that on orientation change, the desired height of the keyboard is achieved and it is working perfectly fine.

But my issue is that on orientation change, the view does not autolayout perfectly as it does in default keyboard on iOS, rather the view changes and then updates the height and then expands to the right of the screen to cover the complete area. ( basically a jerk happens before the keyboard completely loads itself )

Also, on initialization of the keyboard, the view is loaded with the default height and then it updates the custom height. Post that, it applies the auto layout constraint and updates the UI, hence providing the complete layout of the keyboard screen. The whole process looks a bit jerky.

I am using xib with auto layout. 
In case I do not update the custom height of the keyboard, the above mentioned jerks are solved but the height of the keyboard remains default allowed by apple.

There is another thing that there are a lot of views in XIB and hence a lot of constraints. If I remove the constrains, the keyboard loads pretty quick and the custom height is also achieved. But as soon as I rotate the device, the view does not layouts and I am stuck with half keyboard on the screen.

Any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) {
            // Perform custom initialization work here

            if (IS_IPAD) {
                self.portraitHeight = 300;
                self.landscapeHeight = 300;
            }else{
                self.portraitHeight = 257;
                self.landscapeHeight = 203;
            }
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)updateViewConstraints {
        [super updateViewConstraints];

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
        if (_viewWillAppearExecuted)
            [self adjustHeight];

       }
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];

        [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        _viewWillAppearExecuted = YES;
    }
    #pragma mark - Setters/Getters

    - (NSLayoutConstraint *)heightConstraint
    {
        if (!_heightConstraint) {
            _heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:self.portraitHeight];

            _heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityRequired - 1;
        }

        return _heightConstraint;
    }


    #pragma mark - Methods

    - (void)adjustHeight
    {
        if (self.view.frame.size.width == 0 || self.view.frame.size.height == 0)
            return;

        [self.view removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
    //    [self.imageView removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat screenH = screenSize.height;
        CGFloat screenW = screenSize.width;
        BOOL isLandscape =  !(self.view.frame.size.width ==
                              (screenW*(screenW<screenH))+(screenH*(screenW>screenH)));

        self.isLandscape = isLandscape;
        if (isLandscape) {
            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.landscapeHeight;
    //        [self.imageView addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
            [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        } else {
            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.portraitHeight;
    //        [self.imageView addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
            [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        }
    }
```

Try this codes for your problem. First of all do some R&D with this code and let me know.

Comment: also add these properties (nonatomic) CGFloat portraitHeight;
property (nonatomic) CGFloat landscapeHeight;
property (nonatomic) BOOL isLandscape;
property (nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL viewWillAppearExecuted;